# NSURL string content to a label

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, nsurl

Im trying to read some values from a local url when i press a button and i send the value to a label. as soon as i launch the app and i press the button for the first time i get the value. but the second time i press the button the label get no text even though the NSLog message continues to display the value. any idea?

here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)refresh:(id)sender {

NSArray *listItems;


NSString *msg;
NSStringEncoding encoding;


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.177"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding];


listItems = [msg componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

label.text = listItems[0];


NSLog(listItems[0]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `encoding` variable is never initialized with a value, so it has the default value of `0`, which is not a valid value of `NSStringEncoding` according to `NSString.h`. If you run the static analyzer (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> in Xcode), you will get a message that has an uninitialized value when it is used.

Change this line:

```
msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:encoding];
```

to this:

```
msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

(Substitute the appropriate encoding, but `NSUTF8StringEncoding` is a good first guess.)

You should also use a format string to log:

```
NSLog(@"%@", listItems[0]);
```